# How to handle deprecated "Mysql4" classes when rewriting resource models

Tags: magento-1.7, overrides, magento-1.6, best-practice, resource-model

I have to rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat`.

The old resource class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Flat` is still there in Magento 1.7 for backwards compatibility and extends the new one.

A search in the codebase for the full model alias `resource_eav_mysql4_category_flat` did not yield any result. But the `config.xml` of Mage_Catalog contains this line:

```
<deprecatedNode>catalog_resource_eav_mysql4</deprecatedNode>
```

And I don't know where and how `deprecatedNode` is used.

What difficulties are there to expect when rewriting such a resource model? Should I rewrite both classes? Or can I safely ignore the mysql4 class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you develop an extension for personal use that is supposed to work only for you project build on Magento 1.6+ then there are no worries. You should only override `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat` by adding this in the `config.xml` file of your extension:

```
<models>
    <catalog_resource>
        <rewrite>
            <category_flat>Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Category_Flat</category_flat>
        </rewrite>
    </catalog_resource>
</models>
```

If you are building an extension and you want it to work on version before 1.6 you need to override the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Flat` class also. In this case your `config.xml` section should look like this:

```
<models>
    <catalog_resource><!--used for 1.6+ -->
        <rewrite>
            <category_flat>Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Category_Flat</category_flat>
        </rewrite>
    </catalog_resource>
    <catalog_resource_eav_mysql4><!-- used for versions before 1.6 -->
        <rewrite>
            <category_flat>Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Flat</category_flat>
        </rewrite>
    </catalog_resource_eav_mysql4>
</models>
```

You should put all your logic in `Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Category_Flat` and the class for versions before 1.6 should look like this:

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Flat extends Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Category_Flat
{
}
```

This way both versions use the same code.

Answer (score 7):

`deprecatedNode` is used by Magento to try and load `mysql4*` resource model if `resource*`
 wasn't found. Reference the comments from `Mage_Core_Model_Config::getGroupedClassName` and `Mage_Core_Model_Resource::getEntity`:

> ```
> /**
>  * Backwards compatibility for pre-MMDB extensions.
>  * In MMDB release resource nodes <..._mysql4> were renamed to <..._resource>. So <deprecatedNode> is left
>  * to keep name of previously used nodes, that still may be used by non-updated extensions.
>  */
> ```

If there is `resource*` model you should rewrite it, otherwise rewrite `mysql4*` one. Example of rewriting `mysql4*` resource model:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <review_mysql4>
                <rewrite>
                    <review_collection>AW_AdvancedReviews_Model_Mysql4_Review_Collection</review_collection>
                    <review>AW_AdvancedReviews_Model_Mysql4_Review</review>
                </rewrite>
            </review_mysql4>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

The `mysql4*` classes are only there for backwards compatibility for existing implementations which already extended them. I.e. shell classes to avoid forcing existing code to update the extends on everything to continue working.