# Why magento use resource and mysql4 model collection?

Tags: collection, model, resource-model, source-model

What is the purpose of using these two models collection.

1. **Resource**
2. **Mysql4**

why can't we use resource model for all collections.

Why we are using MySql4 collection for simple module

Some one explain.

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer that covered your question?

Answer (score 10):

I would say in magento 1.8 all collections are resource collections.

Resource collections depend on generic implementations for all the SQL-stuff. the idea is to only reimplement the base class to offer support for another sql database, like postgre, oracle or mssql.

The still existing Mysql4 classes are only for backwards compatibility but only extend the resource collection

Update:

> Could you tell me what are the three type of models in magento ?

I'm not sure about this, but I would say you are maybe talking about Models (extending `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`), Resource Models (extending `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract`) and Collections (extending `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract`).

Comment: Could you tell me what are the three type of models in magento ?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 9):

`Mysql4` was deprecated after Magento CE 1.6. [This answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/3796/50) gives some more information about it. A bit more lengthy explanation can be found in [this PDF](http://www.magentocommerce.com/images/uploads/RDBMS_Guide.pdf).

Still, using `Mysql4` classes shouldn't be an issue since it should be backwards compatible.

Comment: Bummer the PDF link no longer available.

Comment: It looks like the Magento RDBMS Guide is depreciated. A little but of searching doesn't turn up much as far as reliable (or legal???) copies of it. So if it's old, remove it. Don't replace it.........