# Where to put custom model function

Tags: magento2, module, magento-1, model, resource-model

I created a module and I have a collection model class(under Model/Mysql4/MyModule/Collection.php), resource class (Model/Mysql4/MyModule.php), abstract model class (Model/MyModule.php) and a setup class (Model/Resource/Mysql4/Setup.php).

I really created them and my module worked perfectly. But I really don't know exact differences between all those models.

I really don't know which function should I put to which file. In a dummy example, I have a function to get all categories with 3 products inside. Where should I define my function and in which model ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why magento use resource and mysql4 model collection?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15362/why-magento-use-resource-and-mysql4-model-collection)

Comment: Thanks @FabianBlechschmidt You are somehow correct. I really know the overal differences , but currently I really don't know where to put my function? I confused with all these...What do you suggest ? Thanks for your comment and answer on that question. It was helpful.

Comment: well, have a file like (Model/Mymodel.php) and make it extend your abstract model. Then, define some functions there.

Comment: @JulienLachal Thanks for your suggestion, but why there ? I mean why not in collection model ? What will happen if I put it to wrong file ? How can I know my function related to which file here ? Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Resource collections are a list of models, everything which filters the collection, orders it or joins stuff into it belongs here.
- resource models are the ORM (more or less), so everything which communicates with the database belongs here. `getItemById()`, `createNewItem()`, etc.
- Model is a data container and the business logic so everything else belongs here.

But depending on the complexity of the business logic I would think about creating more models (without any extend) and helper (when the logic doesn't change any inner status)

Comment: That's whay I wanted to know. You are the man :)